# Amazon Elastic Load Balancer SSL certificate installing How To

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm having troubles making my Amazon-servers secure and I need some help here.

I purchased a wildcard cert, and the company sent me lots of different files:

- DigiCertCA2.pem
- mydomain.pem
- TrustedRoot.pem

And all the files in one file as a chain, and also the same files in .crt -format.

Now I'm trying to install these to the Amazon Elastic Load Balancer, which keeps telling me that the key is in wrong format. Amazon asks for these:

- Private Key:
- Public Key Certificate:
- Certificate Chain:

What do I put and where to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work! Yay!

Here's what I did for anyone else having hard times with this. :)

Amazon ELB will ask for "Private Key", which is the key that you created the first time you needed to give your certificate issuer the CRS-code. My key was in wrong format, which can be seen by looking at the beginning of the file. I had it like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And it should be like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

So I did this to convert it to the right format:

```
sudo openssl rsa -in mydomain.key -out mydomain_new.key
```

Then copy-paste the contents of the mydomain_new.key -file, into the "Private Key" -textarea.

Next is the "Public Key Certificate". This is the contents of mydomain.pem -file.

And finally it's turn for the "Certificate Chain". This is the contents of the DigiCertCA2.pem -file.

And that's it. Amazon accepted it beautifully without complaints.